# Understanding MongoDb .NET driver indexing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently working on an application where MongoDb is used for quite a large amount of data.

The objects I'm storing in MongoDb looks like this:

```
public class PowerPlantDataReading
{
    [BsonId]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("EDIEL")]
    public string EDIEL { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("EndDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("DataReading")]
    public DataReading DataReading { get; set; }
}

public class DataReading
{
    [BsonElement("Version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("OriginalId")]
    public int OriginalId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Double)]
    [BsonElement("Quantity")]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Quality")]
    public string Quality { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }        
}
```

And the query I'm running against MongoDb looks like this:

```
DateTime startDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5);
DateTime endDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

var queryBuilder = Builders<PowerPlantDataReading>.Filter;
var filter = queryBuilder.Where(x => x.EndDate >= startDateUtc && x.EndDate < endDateUtc);

var query = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

return query.Result;
```

The query returns around 825.000 objects, but takes well over 4 minutes to run.

I then tried to create an index like this:

```
IMongoCollection<PowerPlantDataReading> collection = GetCollection();
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<PowerPlantDataReading>.IndexKeys.Descending(x => x.EndDate));
```

Then ran the query again, but to my surprise, it didn't make a difference at all.

I'm not sure if I'm creating the index correctly? If not, how should I create my index to get the best possible performance for the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 minutes to return 825,000 records seems very fast to me. I don't think your going to get that any faster

Comment: Hi @Liam, thanks for your reply :-) I don't know really. The POC application we made a few weeks ago, we did a full table scan for 350.000 records in ~3ms?

Comment: 4 minutes is awful on any db. Usually I would reach for a tool like `explain plan` in MySql but I don't know enough about mongodb to suggest an equivalent. If you did have a tool like that you would likely need to extract the SQL being generated by the C# code.

Comment: Don't forget this isn't just querying the data storage device, this is querying it from .net and creating .net objects, etc. That's an awful lot of iteration, even ignoring the data access segment. What happens if you run the same query in mongo using native (something like robomongo)? You want to remove as many variables as possible to optimise the data access. Your results will be getting skewed currently

Comment: Liam: I tried the exact same query (with index) in robomongo and the query time is the same. Of course, if I'm using paging (defaults to 50 records pr. page in robomongo) is really fast, but we need to extract all 825.000 objects from the result, which is slow.

Comment: Do you figure this out? I was just wondering if your mongodb was local or remote - the latter case could be dominated by network I/O.

Comment: @RobertSchmidt yes, eventually, I figured it out :-) The mongodb was actually hosted on MongoDb Atlas (mongodb cloud) We ended up realising, that we didn't actually need *all* the data in each and every document. Only 3 fields or so was needed for the output. So what we did was using MongoDbs aggregate pipeline to project and "transform" the output as desired. See more about aggragation pipeline here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

The query now takes approx. 3 - 5 minutes to get well over a million documents.